# How do I create a web interface for my homemade IP camera?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ip-camera

I'm using a RaspberryPi-like microcontroller that is running Ubuntu for which I'd like to create a web interface that can be accessed over LAN. Kind of like the way you set up an IP camera or a router. I'm not really sure where to start or what to Google for, so a point in the right direction would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Apache and PHP to create a web service environment on your Raspberry PI. This would allow you to script and connect to a back-end database like MySql or Postgres. Additionally or alternatively, you could also install Wordpress to just serve content. I wrote a quick doco on this on http://headstation.com/archives/configure-apache-php-wordpress/

If you want to stream video into your page, you would need to set up your Pi to stream video. I wrote another doco for this on http://headstation.com/archives/streaming-video-using-pi-camera/

The client side of the video stream can easily be embedded into a html page.